# In layout.xml for a java swing project, the ddMMMyyyy format attaches 00 to year if date entered

Tags: java, swing, date-format

If 12-Jan-14 entered into the date field manually, it becomes 12-Jan-0014. Auto tab is "1:9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy");
```

If you use this format to format your dates it will gives you date like 12-Jan-0014

If you want to display date as 12-Jan-14 then use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy");
```

**Example:**

```
String startdateString = "12-Jan-2014";
SimpleDateFormat fromUser2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
startdateString = fromUser2.format(fromUser2.parse(startdateString));
System.out.println(startdateString);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
12-Jan-14
```